# Pass array of Ids to a database query - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

From another table users are either signed up for rewards or not. 1 means yes, 0 means no.

I need to get all the user_ids from that table that have active as one.

Currently the function says `$this->db->from('user')`.. my question is if there's a way I can specify to only get the users from the array I pass it to?

```
$result = $this->db->get_where('vip_rewards_rebate', ['active'=>1])->result_array();
```

I just want to get the user_id from vip_rewards_rebate

And from that array to only get the users from the users table with the array passed

Answer (score 0):

**CONTROLLER:**

```
 foreach($data as $datafromdb) {
    $data = array('user_id' => $data['user_id']);
    $userinfo = $this->SQLModel->getData($data, 'users');
    print_r($userinfo); //just to check the return data
}
```

**MODEL:**

```
function getData($data, $table) {
$query = $this->db->get_where($table, $data);
return $query->result_array();
}
```

You can store the data on an array if you prefer. :)
I hope this helps.

Comment: I need to pass in those ids to the users table to only display those users.

Comment: Do you mean, displaying user information (from users table )with the IDs you got  from the vip_rewards_rebate?

Comment: You can create a dynamic method on your model which queries an information to the table. Like you have to give a parameter - data array, table name.
On your controller, while you are passing the userid, you can get the return value which is the user information.

For example:

foreach($data as $datafromdb) {
 $userid = $data['user_id'];
 $userinfo = $this->UserModel->getUserInformation($userid, 'users');
}

Comment: yes, because currently theres a query ' $this->db->from('users') but I need to only display people who have active as 1 in vip_rebate .. get their id and from the users table only show them

Comment: So if you got the IDs of active users from vip_rebate, you can use the solution I gave. Create a dynamic function from your model that accepts data array and another parameter for table name. While you are getting the user_id, you query it from the users table using this method. On the other hand, you can use this on your entire system since the method is dynamic. Would you like me to specify it using code?

Comment: I edited my answer, you can check and try it out. :)